# Conditionally deserialize property based on JSON token type

Tags: json.net

In my API I would like to give consumers the option to send a property as either a string identifier or an object, for example:

```
{
    "source": "token_xyz"
}
```

Or

```
{
    "source": {
        "name": "test"
    }
}
```

Depending on the the type (string or object) I'd like to set a specific property on my class:

```
public class MyRequest
{       
    [JsonProperty("source")]
    public SourceUser SourceUser { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("source")]
    public string SourceToken { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I tried decorating both properties with `JsonProperty("source")` but unfortunately this does not work - the object fails to deserialize.

How can I deserialize to the appropriate property based on the JSON type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json.NET does not support having two properties with the same contract property name, possibly because, as explained in the [JSON RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-6):

> An object whose names are all unique is interoperable in the sense
> that all software implementations receiving that object will agree on
> the name-value mappings.  When the names within an object are not
> unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is
> unpredictable.

Thus you will need some sort of [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) to deserialize your `"source"` property.  One easy way to do this is to apply the converter to a private `Source` property that sets & gets either `SourceUser` or `SourceToken` as appropriate:

```
public class MyRequest
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SourceConverter))]
    [JsonProperty]
    object Source
    {
        get
        {
            // Possibly throw an exception if both are non-null?
            return SourceUser ?? (object)SourceToken;
        }
        set
        {
            SourceUser = value as SourceUser;
            SourceToken = value as string;
        }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public SourceUser SourceUser { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string SourceToken { get; set; }
}

class SourceConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("This converter is intended to be applied with [JsonConverter(typeof(SourceConverter))]");
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
            return serializer.Deserialize<SourceUser>(reader);
        else
            return (string)JValue.Load(reader);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/alEdlm).